How to understand the equivalence statement of interval graphs?
An interval graph is an undirected graph formed from a set of intervals on the real line, with a vertex for each interval and an edge between vertices whose intervals intersect.
I saw the theorem below on page 50 of the book Graph classes: a survey (A. Brandstädt , V.B. Le,  J.P. Spinrad). Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics, 1999.)
Theorem 4.3 .1 (Gilmore, Hoffman [444]) Let $G$ be a graph. The following conditions are equivalent:
(i) $G$ is an interval graph;
(ii) The maximal cliques of $G$ can be linearly ordered such that for each vertex $v$, the maximal cliques containing $v$ occur consecutively.
My main confusion lies in the meaning of (ii). What is 'linearly ordered' and what does 'maximal cliques containing  $v$ occur consecutively' mean?"
I provided the following example, which can be tested by SageMath to show it is not an interval graph. However, if I want to verify it using (ii), how should I proceed?


A partial ordering is called a linear ordering provided any two elements are comparable. In this context, it means the maximal cliques can be “sorted” into a list.
For your example, there are four maximal cliques: $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{2,4,5\}$, $\{2,3,5\}$, and $\{3, 5, 6\}$. For brevity let me just write them as three-digit numbers $123$, etc.
Suppose that condition (ii) holds. The three cliques $123$, $235$, and $245$ must appear consecutively because they are the three cliques that contain the vertex $2$. Of these, the pair with $3$ and the pair with $5$ also have to appear consectively. So the only options are $123 < 235 < 245$ and the reverse.
Suppose the order is $123 < 235 < 245$. There are only two options for $356$:

Either $123 < 235 < 245 < 356$, which is a contradiction because $245$ separates $235$ from $356$,
or $356 < 123 < 235 < 245$, which is a contradiction because $123$ separates $356$ from $235$.

The other case is handled similarly.

In general, we can save a bit of effort by not even considering the reverse case. A linear order satisfies (ii) iff its reverse satisfies (ii), so we can assume $123 < 235 < 245$ without loss of generality.

@MishaLavrov You're right, of course. I debated about how quickly to dispense of the reverse case. For OP's sake I decided not to use a wlog simplification, and instead to just say it's the same argument.

As Wikipedia explains, a linear (also called total) order is an order relation on a set under which every pair of elements is comparable. The real numbers are linearly ordered because for all $x,y\in \mathbf R$, either $x \leq y$ or $y \leq x$, but the complex numbers have no natural linear ordering: we can’t say that either one of $3-5i$ and $-7+206i$ is greater than the other.
A set $A$ is maximal with respect to a property $P$ if $A$ has property $P$ but no $B \supsetneq A$ has property $P$. Maximality for other objects than mere sets is defined analogously.
As to the proof, look at the maximal cliques in this graph.  Show that no matter what order you listed them in, there would always be some vertex $v^*$ such that the cliques containing $v^*$ weren’t consecutive, that some clique not containing $v^*$ would appear among them.

It is also nice.

This does not add any content to the existing answers, but the presentation may be helpful.

The maximal cliques in the above graph are $A(=\{1,2,3\}),B,C,D$. Every edge is contained in one of these triangles, so there are no other maximal cliques.
Examples of linear orderings of the maximal cliques are therefore $ABCD$ (shorthand for A<B<C<D) or $BCAD$ etc.
Now the maximal cliques containing $2$ are $\{A,D,B\}$.  The ones containing $5$ are $\{B,D,C\}$. The ones containing $3$ are $\{C,D,A\}$.
So the question is, can we find a linear ordering of $A,B,C,D$ where $D$ and any pair of the others are consecutive?  Clearly the only thing that matters is where $D$ goes in this ordering.
If you put $D$ in the middle, it will not be consecutive with the two at the ends.  If you put $D$ at the end, it will not be consecutive with the two on the other side to it.
Thus your graph does not meet the theorem's criterion to be an interval graph.
